# Collision with a rotated rectangle

Tags: c#, collision-detection, monogame

[image]

I bassically have a sword that is rotating around my white character and an enemy that I have to kill with the sword. However, making a collision with a rotated rectangle is harder than it seems. I already know how to detect a collision with 2 rectangles not rotated but but can't seems to find a method to detect a collision with a rotated rectangle. I've seens methods like the SAT collision detector, but is a bit too complicated.

Could you give me some help on how I can detect the collision with my sword and my enemies?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it is better if you post this question on [Gamedev Stackexchange](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com) as this is not directly related to coding.

Comment: I think your best bet is to properly learn the "separating axis theorem". However, if you do want to do something simpler it might be worth considering just using a smaller rectangle (or a few) that *roughly* cover the shape of the sword. You might be surprised how effective this can be. A lot of games use collision shapes that don't perfectly match the shape of the sprite.

Comment: using multiple collision shapes (as craftworkgames already said) is the easiest way to acomplish your goal without the need for rotated rectangles.
In your case I would just use 3-4 circles which will cover the sword instead of 1 rectangle.